# Android Q: Get list of configured network

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-10.0, android-11

The method to getConfiguredNetworks has now been deprecated in Android Q. I was using this feature in order to determine whether a Wifi network has any security such as WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_EAP. All of these are now deprecated and i am not sure whether there is any alternative. Google suggests to use WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder#build() but this is for connecting to new network, not for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

[WiFi scanning](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-scan) allows you to get the list of networks in range.

Then you can parse [`ScanResult.capabilities`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html#capabilities), which should - among others - contain the encryption info of the network (WPA/WPA2/etc).
Granted, it would be more convenient to have a proper object rather than a string, but here we are.